# Is there a way to change the default shell in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

When opening the new Windows Terminal, it opens up **PowerShell.**
Also by default new tabs are **PowerShell.**

You have to manually switch to your desired shell.
[image]

Is there a way in the settings *JSON file* to change this to *cmd* or something else?

windows version : 1903

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Did you install the new Windows Terminal UWP application from the Windows Store?

Comment: yes, the preview version

Comment: The tags on this question may need tweaking. The `terminal` tag is too generic and it's not a direct `powershell` question.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Open Windows Terminal JSON settings. Next, in `profiles` array find the object for the shell you're searching and copy the `guid` value from it. The last step is to paste this value into the `defaultProfile` attribute.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",

    "defaultProfile": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}"

    ....
```

It may change your default shell.

Comment: Note that the curly braces must be included: `{CMD-GUID-GOES-HERE}`

Comment: Note also that in mine,  (Version 0.9.443.0), there's no "globals" section, it starts thusly: (after I changed mine to use PS7/Core)

```// To view the default settings, hold "alt" while clicking on the "Settings" button.
// For documentation on these settings, see: https://aka.ms/terminal-documentation
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
    "defaultProfile": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
    "profiles": [
        {
            // Make changes...
```

Comment: I just replaced the defaultProfile (line 11) with the GUID mentioned in the Ubuntu array. Worked fine for me

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with the "Open in Windows Terminal" command in File Explorer

Answer (score 15):

The procedure requires some knowledge about JSON file format. Here is a brief
outline. Every member is represented as `"name":"value"` pair. Arrays use
square brackets and Objects use curly brackets. Read this [Wikipedia: JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
for more details.

### Procedure:

- Open Windows Terminal. Click on the down arrow symbol <kbd>˅</kbd> from
  menu bar. This will open a drop down menu from which select Settings option.
  Alternatively use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open Settings directly.
  Here is a sample screenshot:

[image: windows-terminal-settings]

- After selecting the Settings, Notepad (or the default text editor) will open
  `profiles.json` file. Here is a sample, see first JSON object i.e. `"globals"`.

```
"globals" : 
{
    "alwaysShowTabs" : true,
    "copyOnSelect" : false,
    "defaultProfile" : "{12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB}",
    "initialCols" : 120,
    "initialRows" : 30,
```

We are interested in `defaultProfile` name. The value with 128-bit format
`{12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB}` is called [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Assume its like
a *nickname* for default shell :)

- Now in that file, find `"name" : "cmd"` pair (or `"commandline" : "cmd.exe"` pair)
  for Command Prompt. There will be a `"guid"` pair adjacent of it. Copy the value,
  i.e. the 128-bit *nickname*. And paste it to globals > defaultProfile.
- Restart Windows Terminal.

If you have installed Windows Terminal *without* Windows Store, the actual path
of the `profiles.json` is `"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\profiles.json"`.
You can directly open the path in any text editor.

### Further Readings

- [microsoft/terminal: Profiles.json Documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/cascadia/SettingsSchema.md)
- [microsoft/terminal: Editing Windows Terminal JSON Settings](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/user-docs/UsingJsonSettings.md)

Comment: That json is not longer valid. `globals` is not allowed

Answer (score 7):

Edit settings and change the defaultProfile value to the GUID value of the profile you want to be the default. For example:

```
{
"$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",

"defaultProfile": "{d3f31bee-5823-5ed8-8e04-f31ed54f2cd9}",

...
```

Answer (score 1):

This setting is now available in the UI. Open Windows Terminal settings using the drop-down in the title bar and click Settings. In the Startup section you can change the default terminal. You can select the classic Command Line, Powershell and also Git Bash or WSL distro shells if any are installed.