# Run Anaconda's ipython on Windows 10's Terminal in one go

Tags: windows, batch, anaconda, ipython, windows-terminal

As the title suggests, I would like to run `Anaconda`'s `ipython` on Windows 10's `Windows Terminal (Preview)` (preferrably in the `cmd.exe` tab) in one go.

By ***in one go*** I mean, with a single shortcut or batch file, I can start to work with `ipython` environment in Windows 10's `Windows Terminal (perview)`.

Currently I can do it in 3 steps:

1. Open `Windows Terminal (Preview)`. Alternatively, I can create a shortcut to the program, whose path is `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.5.2661.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe`. I have changed the preference so that the default tab is `cmd.exe` instead of `PowerShell`.
2. Within `Windows Terminal (Preview)`, start Anaconda's environment by entering `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Anaconda3`, where `C:\Anaconda3` is my installation folder. Then each line of the prompt will start with `(base)`.
3. Enter `ipython` in the prompt. Ipython will then start. The prompt now becomes like `In [1]:`.

But I do not know how to combine the above 3 steps into one, with a batch file or anything. Any idea that helps the automation is much appreciated!

***Edit:*** For your reference, the content of `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat` is

```
@REM Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
@REM SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
@REM Test first character and last character of %1 to see if first character is a "
@REM   but the last character isn't.
@REM This was a bug as described in https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst/issues/60
@REM When Anaconda Prompt has the form
@REM   %windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" "C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3"
@REM Rather than the correct
@REM    %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K ""C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\builder\Miniconda3""
@REM this solution taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31359867
@set "_args1=%1"
@set _args1_first=%_args1:~0,1%
@set _args1_last=%_args1:~-1%
@set _args1_first=%_args1_first:"=+%
@set _args1_last=%_args1_last:"=+%
@set _args1=

@if "%_args1_first%"=="+" if NOT "%_args1_last%"=="+" (
    @CALL "%~dp0..\condabin\conda.bat" activate
    @GOTO :End
)

@REM This may work if there are spaces in anything in %*
@CALL "%~dp0..\condabin\conda.bat" activate %*

:End
@set _args1_first=
@set _args1_last=
```

Comment: Thanks for asking! I list the content in the edit to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Procedure:

- Open Windows Terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open
  `settings.json` file in default text editor.
- Add this following JSON object to the `profile` array.

```json
{
    "guid": "{ee4fe116-1375-4c00-925c-1e361f99496d}",
    "name": "Anaconda ipython",
    "commandline": "cmd.exe /C C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Anaconda3 & ipython",
    "hidden": false
},
```

- Change the `defaultProfile` value to that GUID to automatically open Anaconda
  ipython on startup.

```json
"defaultProfile": "{ee4fe116-1375-4c00-925c-1e361f99496d}",
```

### Explanation:

What does the `commandline` do? It executes `cmd.exe` with the `activate.bat`
file. The `/C` option carries out the command in `cmd.exe` then terminates.
If you want to prevent termination use `/K` option. The Ampersand symbol (&)
is to execute `ipython` command after executing the `activate.bat` file.

The GUID is randomly generated using `uuidgen`, check if it does not match with
other profiles GUID in that JSON file. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1482509/726810) for more details
on how to edit JSON file.