# Is there a way to make Windows Terminal the default container for CMD and Powershell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

If I open the new Windows Terminal, I can then open tabs for CMD, Powershell, Wsl, etc.

But if I run Powershell.exe or CMD.exe directly or open a .ps1/.bat script, they will be shown using their respective (ugly) standard window, not inside Windows Terminal.

I want to know if there's a way to make then always open inside Windows Terminal, no matter how I started them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know if there's a way to make then always open inside Windows Terminal, no matter how I started them.

**At this time it is not possible.**  In order for this to work it requires OS support, which at this time, does not exist.

> This will require an OS feature. I'm updating the title to represent the default terminal OS change.

Now if you were to add Windows Terminal to the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Menu, retrain your brain to always use that, then configure the appropriate profiles for Windows Terminal you would likely get to a 90% solution.

**Otherwise, as of today and Windows Terminal 1.15 currently is not possible to replace the Command Prompt with Windows Terminal.**

Source:

- [Change Windows OS to support default terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/492)
- [Totally unsupported hacks - Add Windows Terminal to the Win+X Shortcut menu](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TotallyUnsupportedHacksAddWindowsTerminalToTheWinXShortcutMenu.aspx)
- [Is there a way to change the default shell in Windows Terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/1456511/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-shell-in-windows-terminal)

With the release of Windows 11 it became possible to set Windows Terminal as the default terminal. This functionality has not yet been added to Windows 10.