# Is there a way to ssh into Linux PCs from windows with oneclick - using windows terminal?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, terminal, windows-terminal

I use SSH authentication and it works fine.
Right now I have a batch file(.bat) which has "ssh username@server"
In one click I connect to that particular linux machine's Shell. But it opens regular/default windows console.

Is there a way that I can connect to that a linux machine's Shell but with "Windows Terminal" with just one-click?

Comment: At this time there really isn't any way to replace the command prompt and/or PowerShell with Windows Terminal.  I mention that fact because that would be one of the only ways to accomplish what you want[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1557625/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-terminal-the-default-container-for-cmd-and-powers/1557629#1557629)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wt.exe ssh username@server
```

Save it as a batch file (or as a target for a shortcut) and it will open your default profile in Windows Terminal.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments