# How to associate PS1 file type to Windows Terminal with PowerShell profile

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I want to let Windows Terminal run PS1 script while using the blue-backgrounded "PowerShell" profile. If I simply switch to Windows Terminal as default Windows console, double-clicking a PS1 file will open it in the black-backgrounded default profile.

I tried changing PS1 file association in `HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\shell\0\command` to

```
wt.exe new-tab -p "PowerShell" -c "powershell.exe %1"
```

But it seems that WT will ignore the profile choice and open a black "Default" tab as long as there is a command following. Is there any way to force WT to use a certain profile while also running some commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have scripts run in Windows Terminal by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/1635556/is-it-possible-to-have-scripts-run-in-windows-terminal-by-default)

Comment: Why don't you simply pimp out your [powershell pofile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3) and set it to whatever colors you want?

Comment: @harrymc Ack!  I read it as a duplicate as well at first, but then realized on a second-reading that the OP here has actually already set WT as the default terminal.  This is about getting a particular profile in WT to be the default when running a command.  I've retracted my close-vote.

Comment: Retracted the same, although I think [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/1635685/8672) in there can be modified to answer this one as well.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Because I want terminal to match the profile (background color) according to what was running. If I use PowerShell profile as default then it won't look right when I'm running BAT or COM scripts.

Comment: This is a long shot.  You might want to check out the "all users all hosts" option for powershell profile.  This will cause the profile script to run no matter how powershell was invoked.  Then you can put whatever customization you want in the profile script.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the appearance of the "Defaults" profile will change how the Terminal appears when launched in response to a commandline process being launched.

There's some heuristic for attempting to match the commandline of the process being launched to one of your profiles, but I believe that only works for exact matches. For example, `powershell.exe` should launch your "Windows PowerShell" profile, but `powershell.exe -NoLogo -c foo.ps1` will fall back to the defaults.