# Replace "cmd" to start Windows Terminal instead of cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-terminal

I am now using Windows Terminal as my main terminal on Windows. It's an awesome project.

However, I still have the habit of using win+R, then "cmd", then "Enter".

I'd like to replace the default behavior of "cmd" to start Windows Terminal instead this way:
""%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" -w 0 new-tab"

I've tried the same method that Notepad++ uses to do it with the debugger entry in registry but Notepadd++ has a specific command to tell him so. When doing the same with cmd, it repeateadly open non-stop because a debugger will try to attach to "cmd". And since "debugger" is wt, it goes into an infinite loop.

I tried adding it here: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\

Anything I haven't found that could be the answer?

Yes, I know I can use "wt" in run. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Really a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1557625/1210833), although with a slightly different spin ("replace" rather than "default container for").  But I think the answer is the same for this one -- Not yet.  I was curious to see if I could come up with some way to still use your "muscle memory" of "CMD+R, cmd".  I tried a `cmd.bat` added to a directory at the beginning of the path to see if it would run without the extension, but no luck there, either.