# can't select windows terminal as system default

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-terminal

I saw some tutorials on how to do it but it seems like I don't have the option! any clues on how to fix?  It seems like the option is disabled or something

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are not apparently running the required version of Windows 10 necessary to do what you want

Comment: You would have to be running (21390) which was a developer Insider Preview build[.](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-terminal-can-now-be-the-default-windows-10-console/) However, it’s no longer available, due to the start of Windows 11 Insider Preview builds[.](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10594).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make Windows Terminal the default container for CMD and Powershell?](https://superuser.com/questions/1557625/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-terminal-the-default-container-for-cmd-and-powers)

Comment: @Ramhound Could you update your answer on the question that I linked to add that it is available under Preview?  I consider this a duplicate of that question, really, but I'd like to make sure the answer there is up-to-date.

Comment: Mik, not sure why you reposted this here after I provided a comment on your Stack Overflow question pointing you to an answer here on Super User that said you had to be running Insider.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - The duplicates answers hasn’t been updated.  I am not inclined to update it since due to various issues with the feature

Comment: @Ramhound Oops - missed that.  Didn't notice that it was gone now.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - This isn't to excuse the author submitting the same question to multiple communities (the author should have allowed the question to be migrated), but submitting a comment on Stack Overflow, isn't an actual answer.  I am of the opinion that it still is not possible to set Windows Terminal to the default prompt on Windows 10 (due to it only being avavible to Windows Insider builds that are not technically Windows 10).

Comment: @Ramhound I would still say that this question is a duplicate of the other one linked here on Super User, and it should be answered there rather than promoting another duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw some tutorials on how to do it but it seems like I don't have the option! any clues on how to fix?

You are not running the required Windows 10 Insider Preview (Developer) build required to enable it.

> This setting is currently in the Windows Insider Program Dev Channel build and can be found inside the console property sheet. We have also added this setting to the settings UI in Windows Terminal Preview.

> Any clues on how to fix?

You would have to upgrade to the proper Insider Preview build in the Developer channel (specifically [21390](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/05/26/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-21390/)+).  It appears that 21390 is likely to become Windows 10 version 21H2.

Source: [Windows Terminal Preview 1.9 Release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-9-release/)

Comment: This answer was written before Windows 11 was announced, it’s obviously invalidated, but given the context answered the question.