# How to hard set Windows Terminal as default for ALL applications and users?

Tags: terminal, windows-11, windows-terminal

The [conventional method](https://www.anoopcnair.com/windows-terminal-default-command-line-app/#:%7E:text=Option%202%20Windows%20Terminal%20%E2%80%93%20Change%20the%20Windows%20Terminal%20as%20Default%20Terminal%20Application) to set a default terminal application doesn't apply to 2 types of applications:

1. Running a shell (e.g: Powershell) as administrator
2. Running a application-specific such as Git Bash or Anaconda PowerShell

In both cases, running either of these will open the classic conhost even if you have Windows Terminal set as the default terminal application.

I've tried the following:

- Turning "Developers Mode" in Windows on
- Set "Windows Terminal" to run as administrator via the app's setting (this only opens Windows Terminal whenever opened and automatically asks the user for administrative permission on startup)

How do I set it such that Windows Terminal runs on **ALL** terminal application regardless of the shell type and all on administrative permission?

For reference, these are the settings I've set, please see the imgur links below:

[Developer Terminal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTGSp.png)

[Conhost Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkbNE.png)

Comment: Developer Mode has absolutely no say in if Windows Terminal is used as the default terminal.  I would highly encourage you to disable it.  Furthermore, you do understand an Administrator will be able to revert your choice in terminals, right? [I would need some more information, in the past Windows 10 21H2 had some issues with setting the default terminal to Windows Terminal.](https://superuser.com/questions/1662103/cant-select-windows-terminal-as-system-default/1662124#1662124) you should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Right, the thing is there's no administrator managing my computer. I'm the only user and my microsoft account is set as an admin

Comment: Do you have Windows Terminal profiles defined for both `Git Bash` and `Anaconda`?

Comment: Disregarding any 3rd part programs, I can also confirm that running any shell app, batch file, etc as Administrator makes it launch in conhost instead of Terminal, despite the latter being the system-wide default. Is there any way to change THAT?