# Change default windows size of Windows Terminal

Tags: wsl2, windows-terminal

I would like to change the default windows size of Windows Terminal.
Is there any configuration option in `settings.json` that allows me to change the default size?

Thanks!

Comment: [Yes](https://superuser.com/questions/1456511/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-shell-in-windows-terminal?rq=1) there is.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound :)