# How can I get a Windows Terminal prompt without PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-11, windows-terminal

I am using Windows 11. It seems Windows Terminal is preinstalled. However when the Terminal tabbed interface starts I got the PowerShell 7 prompt in the Terminal. (If I type exit in hope PowerShell is just running over an other shell, then the whole thing exits)

**Question**

Is there any way to start Windows Terminal just with the normal shell?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to change the default shell in Windows Terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/1456511/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-shell-in-windows-terminal)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any way to start Windows Terminal just with the normal shell?

You can set the default profile within the Settings tab for Windows Terminal.

> [image]

Source: [How to Make Windows Terminal Always Open With Command Prompt on Windows 11](https://www.howtogeek.com/746156/how-to-make-windows-terminal-always-open-with-command-prompt-on-windows-11/)

Strictly speaking Windows Terminal isn’t actually an emulator, it’s a host application (Microsoft’s own words), which leverages hooks within Microsoft to become the default host application for Command Prompt, PowerShell, and WSL. It simply replaces (or lives along side of on Windows 10) the default host application built-into Windows.

Comment: Btw, if you type `cmd` into the search box or hit Windows+R and then enter `cmd`, it will bring `CMD.EXE` up in Windows Terminal. In fact, I believe any conventional way of launching `CMD.EXE` that worked before will still work, but use Windows Terminal.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - That’s only applicable to Windows 11 not Windows 10 and **only** if you have configured Windows Terminal to be the default host application on Windows 11 (that’s not possible on Windows 10)